# Understanding transactionscope timeouts

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, transactionscope

My current understanding of transactionscope timeouts.

If a transaction has been running longer than the set timeout time it throws an exception when 
transaction.complete() is called.  So if the processing within the transaction has been going on 
for X minutes we still would have to wait X minutes after which the transaction.complete is called.

In our case, we are using transactionscope from within a webservice - the end user of the web request
will have to wait for X minutes before the transaction is aborted and the exception bubbled back.

However, the default timeout for a HttpWebRequest is 100 seconds (according to msdn). Since the client times 
out in 100 seconds we have a timeout in transactionscope of a minute. This ensures database consistency.

Is my understanding of timeouts correct?

Question: We would like to minimize the time it takes for the end user to know the results of the transaction. To minimize latency we decided to split up the code using nested transactionscopes - each with a timeout of say 15 seconds. If a child transaction is taking longer than a 15 seconds we  abort the transaction as a whole.

Here it seems that the child transaction's timeout is ignored. I get an exception only after the 
parent transaction's timeout is called. In the following code ChildTransaction() always returns true. 
What is the recommended approach to minimize the latency? **The code shows default timeout of 1 minute just so the code is cleaner**

```
    internal bool RootTransaction()
    {           
        using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                bool result = ChildTransaction();

                //The result is always true. 
                if (!result)
                    return result;                                     

                for (int counter = 0;counter <= 10;counter++)
                {                       
                    //Either sleep OR do some processing 
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    //
                    //Dosomeprocess()
                }                    
                transaction.Complete();                    
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                    
                return false;
            }
        }                           
    }

    internal bool ChildTransaction()
    {            
        using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
    //Sleep for 70 seconds
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(70000);
                transaction.Complete();                    
            }                
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }                
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Replacing exceptions with a true/false return code is almost never a good idea. Can I clarify: are you using transactions *as part of* the web-service call? Such distributed transactions can be truly deadly. Or is the transaction local to the web-service implementation?

Comment: No. The transactions are not part of the web-service call. The web-service mention was just to set the context. The services are atomic and some of them deal with data inserts that require transactions. Also, the true false is just for testing purposes. We have separate logging framework etc for the exception.

Comment: K. For the record, I'm not sure I would expect much from the child transaction to be respected. The outermost transaction rules with TS. The timeout shouldn't double though; if the timeout is X seconds, then it is x seconds from when it first does anything - not x seconds then x seconds on the call. It is a bit tricky though because in your example you aren't seeming to involve any transacted resource - which makes it hard to talk about specific behaviour. But the timeout is on the transaction itself not operations.

Comment: The timeout is fine. By default, If the total transaction takes more than a minute it will be aborted. My questions - 1) If the child transaction by itself takes more than a minute it does not throw an exception 2) The transaction timeout always is checked only when the transaction is committed (which can take more than a minute depending on its processing). What is the recommended way to minimize wait time for an end user? I need my end user to get the result back in 15 secs. So, I split the trans' into nested ones with a timeout of 15 secs. Looks like child trans timeouts are not respected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look at it this way:

The length of the transaction is only determined when you call trans.Complete() or exit the transaction scope. Take the following code:

```
using (var trans= new TransactionScope())
{
Threading.Sleep(99999);
trans.Complete()
}
```

There is no way to throw a timeout exception while inside the sleep routine and it wouldn't make sense if it did. And so using transaction timeouts (this way at least) can only guarantee that if the transaction takes longer than your timeout, it will not be commited.

If you are just executing one query (which I wouln't know what you use the transactions for) then you could set the query/command timeout (or whatever you call it). IIRC, your query will return immediately after the timeout expires.

Another way would be to set your web service request timeout and just assume that the webservice is taking too long to respond because of whatever was inside your transaction.

EDIT:
You could try:

- Spawning your transaction on a different thread and then wait for it to complete (using Thread.Join(timeout)) on your main thread (one used by the webservice call). So if it doesn't terminate before the timeout you specified then you could stop waiting and return a timeout error (dont forget to signal the other thread to abort the transaction).
- Assuming you are only performing SQL queries inside those transactions, you could use the "BEGIN TRANSACTION" keyword to specify the transaction in the sql script (hacky indeed). Then you could just specify the command timeout and execute all this in a single line of code. But then this requires you to move everything you do inside the transaction into a sql script which may or may not be possible for you... and it isn't clean.